# Select rows where count() = n

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, database-performance

I'm implementing a search functionality where the results should show results page and for each result, the main image and up to 3 more thumbnails.

Right now in the procution version, for each ad it makes 1 select to return the images from the database which it terrible for performance, so I've changed it to a single query that does basically the following:

```
select * from AdImages order by IsMainImage desc, AdImageId
```

and returns something like:

```
AdImageId   AdId        IsMainImage FilePath
----------- ----------- ----------- ----------------------------------------
1           1           1           9c513f10-5480-4e41-89c6-074b36051999.jpg
5           2           1           f64f9c12-398e-445f-9724-baebe40930b1.jpg
6           4           1           8187d566-b296-4ab0-85e5-b9fc86f293b7.jpg
8           5           1           b8165008-09b3-4258-bf54-043195138344.jpg
10          6           1           86c636ed-f4ed-4f7e-8c7e-fc0b24faa956.jpg
11          7           1           4409a3fd-2bc0-4512-9850-6f5146193e50.jpg
13          8           1           b9b66c48-92b7-479a-a85d-dc6d26b03ebc.jpg
14          9           1           9f3f06ad-4fe1-43a5-8cce-3bb804bb10b7.jpg
16          10          1           016c30dc-5ee8-40d8-9d0f-398f444d7a7b.jpg
19          11          1           e5e56602-1af7-492b-8a8e-b61ac86b751b.jpg
2           1           0           02d44ce1-0de6-4e22-b4ef-043a72e9b5e8.jpg
3           1           0           8c4e19db-faff-44c2-9aab-6a96ab2a8e22.jpg
4           1           0           d8c2464a-277c-40fa-ab43-d2455e819e7e.jpg
7           4           0           d1430ae0-df51-43b7-acea-50d606eee5ba.jpg
9           5           0           b947ae4c-653d-4c27-9edd-567d977e1af3.jpg
12          7           0           3080c947-3769-4762-bb29-f1f9c5303ecd.jpg
15          9           0           d2543ce3-1e65-4a18-80d6-584de0025f1a.jpg
17          10          0           03b26d6a-4e0c-4393-9b5a-d9f2a24d36da.jpg
18          10          0           cde5dacd-3984-4cea-b56f-c3a6c5b82fa0.jpg
20          11          0           9e286ac0-25b1-4a05-af83-26e5d0002c2a.jpg
21          11          0           b1266770-9926-462c-8ec0-e965b21021eb.jpg
22          11          0           0542bd2a-4c4b-41d4-b51b-d311f42f0da9.jpg
23          11          0           b1cc44c9-50c4-4e81-bc9a-a0a4b515e709.jpg
```

My local db is very small but I could notice a very good performance gain, anyway, I think it could be better if I could make this query return only up to 4 rows for each ad instead of all the rows for each ad as it is doing. But to do so, it should be something like `where count(AdId) == 4` which I'm not sure is possible.

I'm also using Entity Framework here. Any extra advice would be very welcome.

Comment: Do you want to return only 4 random images for each AD even if there are more? And do you want this query in LINQ or SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Window Function`

```
select AdImageId ,AdId ,IsMainImage ,FilePath 
from(
select row_number() over(partition by Adid order by IsMainImage desc, AdImageId) rn,* 
from AdImages)a
where rn<=4
```

Comment: I would also order by `IsMainImage desc` to be sure do get the main image.

Comment: @tschmit007 - Yeah missed it

Comment: I don't think I can do this with linq to entities right? best bet is to make a stored procedure, right?

Comment: @user3900456 - sorry i don't know linq so cannot comment on same

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding you correctly, you can just return the `TOP xx` results.

```
SELECT TOP(3) * from AdImages order by IsMainImage desc, AdImageId;
```

This will return only the top 3 results.